# Test-DbaDiskAlignment Not Working

Tags: sql-server, dbatools

```
    PS H:\> Test-DbaDiskAlignment -ComputerName Test_Server
    WARNING: [Test-DbaDiskAlignment][22:09:54] Can't connect to Test_Server
    WARNING: [Test-DbaDiskAlignment][22:09:54] CIM query to Test_Server failed.
```

I am very new to using dbatools. Would someone be able to help me with this error please.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Check computer name and if the account has permission to the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post, do you meet the minimum requirements? Is remoting enabled?
https://dbatools.io/install/

Otherwise run it with the verbose flag and let us know what you get:

```
Test-DbaDiskAlignment -ComputerName Test_Server -Verbose
```

Also what version of both the dbatools module and powershell are you using?

Powershell version:

```
$PSVersionTable
```

dbatools version:

```
Get-Module dbatools
```

Answer (score 1):

Is SQL Server installed on this computer? If not, pass in the `-NoSqlCheck` switch parameter. If you don't use this switch and SQL Server isn't installed, it'll skip over the checks and report this error incorrectly.